# Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/XXXX/public_html/seo/index.php on line 287

Tags: php

```
 $ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$lurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_followlocation, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookie.txt');
```

What's wrong with this code?

Idk why but the formatting is messed up on here. It's the line:

Comment: Which line is 287?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_followlocation, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 CURLOPT_followlocation
```

To:

```
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
```